# python variable name of list object, best practice

Tags: python

I have a variable which will hold a list of customer ids.

The code is like this:

```
customers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for customer in customers:
    do logic
```

My question is whether the following name is better practice in Python for readability?

```
customer_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for customer in customer_list:
    do logic
```

The issue comes up because I don't know what is more readable and better practice.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: maybe you find answer in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as opinion-based because it honestly is - I prefer `customers` over `customer_list`, but ideally you have something like type hinting to tell you what type the `customers` should be (a list of integers). Neither is *wrong*, and the fact that you're thinking about it at all is a good sign.

Comment: Obviously subjective but I do not think `customer_list ` is better. It shouldn't particularly matter that the list is a list. It's an enumerable collection, of some kind. Would you have `age_int`, `name_str`?

Comment: I would use `customer_ids`. With `customers` I would expect classes or rows with all data. But I wouldn't use `_list`

Comment: the issue is that for readability now customers and customer are easily confused as a readability issue, how to name the list object then?